# Making wordpress menu horizontal

Tags: menus, themes

Hey guys am new to wordpress development actually.I am trying to make my wordpress menu horizontal at the top below the title name.

My `header.php`

In my header file i have assigned the menus with a class like

```
<nav class="mythirdclass">
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>
```

In my `style.css`

in the style.css file i have given like

```
.mythirdclass {
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
   display: inline;
}
```

But this code isnt working at all ..i want the menu to be appear in horizontal way.

Thanks for the help..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to position output of `wp_nav_menu()` in horizontal line. Your should try styling `<li>` elements, instead of all `<div>`. Also `width: 100%;` should be removed.

Something like this seems to work:

```
.mythirdclass li {
   float: left;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 1em;
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
display:inline-block;
```

That doesn't work, try activating a theme you know works, like 2012, and compare yours to it.